# MySQL Remote-Access impossible

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I have problems to connect to my MySQL-Server via remote-access.

I am using the **MySQL Workbench**. Everything is set up correctly (I mind). The MySQL Server is running on Ubuntu 16.04 with Plesk.

My user has all rights (including GRANT), the remote-restriction in the `my.cnf` is commented out:

```
# bind-address = ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

Database-Name is "localhost" and I try to connect via the IP-address of my server.

Important to say is, that there's no user-error (e.g. wrong password or missing permission). So I think, it's an Firewall-problem.

Comment: Could be indeed a firewall issue, but there can be other. See if my trouble shooting video can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY&t=842s

Answer (score 1):

**1. Change mysql config**

Find the mysql config file

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

OR (if above file points to !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/)

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Comment out following lines (IF ANY)

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

This allows outside connections other than localhost (127.0.0.1)

```
#skip-networking
```

This allow listening of TCP/IP ports

**2. Change GRANT privilege**

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Following ensures that user has access to all schemas in the database

```
*.*
```

% ensures that user can connect from any IP address / Network

```
'USERNAME'@'%'
```

Then run this command to apply the changes.

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**3. Restart MySQL server**

Restart the server

```
service mysql restart
```

**4. Connect to server**

Default port for MySQL is

```
3306
```

You can also find the port that it's running using this command

```
netstat -tln
```

It should return something like this

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

**In MySQL Workbench**

Use the SQL Server's IP address as Host name

Use 3306 as Port Number

Use the User that you granted access to

Use 'password' that you used in the GRANT command

Please refer to https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/

Comment: My scenario: Ubuntu 16.04 with Plesk, 1st step was working for me. Thanks!